# How do you only keep numbers and commas and dots (that occur between numbers) with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say you have the following string:

```
var string = "This shirt, is very nice. It costs DKK 1.500,00";
```

I want a function that will return `1.500,00`.

The point is, that I only want to allow commas and dots that occur between numbers so I don't end up with: `,.1.500,00`

How would you do this using regexp in javascript?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this - `\b\d[.,\d]*\b` ?

Comment: apparently, it doesn't matches when , or . is after the number :)

Comment: `\b` matches a position between `\w` (`[0-9A-Za-z_])`) & `\W`.  So `\b\d[.,\d]*\b` would work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
"This shirt, is very nice. It costs DKK ,.1.500,00,.".match(/(\d+\.\d+)+,\d+/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the required one:

```
\d((?=([.,]\d|\d)).)*
```

`\d` matches a digit

`(?=([.,]\d|\d))` is a look-ahead which ensures that the following character is either a digit or a `.` or `,` followed by a digit.

The `.` matches any character and `*` allows zero or more occurrence of preceding pattern